# Не получается правильно получить файл по URI Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Необходимо получить файл, который потом отправится на сервер.

Кидаю через Intent

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
intent.type = "file/*"
startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE)
```

Получаю в onActivityResult во Fragment

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
         Log.d("Код", resultCode.toString())
         Log.d("Код r", requestCode.toString())
         Log.d("Код d", data.toString())
        when(requestCode) {
            PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE -> {
                data?.let {
                    val file = File(data.data.toString())
                    val format = getFileFormat(file.name)
                    if(!isSupportFormat(format)){
                        Snackbar.make(getView()!!, "Неподдерживаемый формат", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show()
                        return
                    }



                    Log.d("File format", format)
                    Log.d("File", file.name)
                    Log.d("File size", file.length().toString())
                }

            }
```

Log

```
2020-03-31 19:41:33.535 8480-8480/com.app.peshkariki D/Код: -1
2020-03-31 19:41:33.535 8480-8480/com.app.peshkariki D/Код r: 100
2020-03-31 19:41:33.535 8480-8480/com.app.peshkariki D/Код d: Intent { dat=content://com.mi.android.globalFileexplorer.myprovider/external_files/app-release_gruzo.apk flg=0x1 }
2020-03-31 19:41:33.538 8480-8480/com.app.peshkariki D/File format: apk
2020-03-31 19:41:33.538 8480-8480/com.app.peshkariki D/File: app-release_gruzo.apk
2020-03-31 19:41:33.538 8480-8480/com.app.peshkariki D/File size: 0
```

при отправке file через Okhttp, Okhttp падает с ошибкой не возможности нахождения файла

```
2020-03-31 21:03:17.455 20644-22309/com.app.peshkariki W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: content:/com.mi.android.globalFileexplorer.myprovider/external_files/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8.doc (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Я допускаю что вы неправильно получаете размер файла. Его лучше будет в стринг а потом размер брать

Comment: @Andrew я не совсем вас понял

Comment: в каком виде должен быть отправлен файл на сервер? вы ведь планируете как-то его отправлять?

Comment: @Andrew ну перед отправкой мне нужно сначала размер проверить, а так
с помощью MultipartBody.Builder()

Comment: уже есть метод, принимающий File

Answer (score 0):

Вот есть способ для получения размера файла:

```
private String getRealSizeFromUri(Context context, Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE };
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: если вы смогли из него получить имя и другие данные, значит все верно

Comment: а можно как нибудь по этому uri создать File?
Просто когда я отправляю через Okhttp, то он пишет, что файл не находит

Comment: 2020-03-31 21:03:17.455 20644-22309/com.app.peshkariki W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: content:/com.mi.android.globalFileexplorer.myprovider/external_files/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8.doc (No such file or directory)

Comment: Насколько я знаю то по uri файл создать можно, для этого и есть filepicker встроенный)

Comment: Не припомню как прикладывается файл к запросу в `OkHttp`... Но по `Uri` 100%-но можно получить только поток: [`context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#openInputStream(android.net.Uri)). Если нужен именно файл, то в качестве костыля, можно сохранить этот поток во временный файл, отправить этот файл и после удалить.